# How to style each item of a Spinner in Android (fontColor, typeface)

Tags: user-interface, spinner, adapter, android

I want to dislplay spinners for selecting fontColor and fontFamily. The aim is to give the user a preview of the font/color inside the spinner. So I need to style each item of the spinner individually.

How can I achive that?

Comment: Put that logic in your `SpinnerAdapter`, particularly `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`.

Comment: Show your code where you setting the adapter.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterFontColor = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.colors,
    R.drawable.spinner);
  adapterFontColor.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  sp_fontColor.setAdapter(adapterFontColor);`

Comment: can anyone help please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I guessed you are going to customize Spinner in Android.

First of all, please refer this xml code snippet.

```
activity_main.xml
 <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/service_spinner"
                    style="@style/Drop_Down_Spinner_Style" />

styles.xml
<style name="Drop_Down_Spinner_Style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/spinner_normal_height</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_bg1</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownWidth">match_parent</item>
    </style>

/drawable/spinner_bg1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffeb4175" />

            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

            <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
        </shape></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />

            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />

            <padding android:bottom="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:top="0dp" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>


This is custom adapter class for Spinner
    public class NailsSpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
            }

            SpinnerModel item = items.get(position);
            TextView item_title = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview_in_spinner_item);
            item_title.setText(item.getValue());

            return vi;
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
            }

            SpinnerModel item = items.get(position);
            TextView item_title = (TextView) vi
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_text);
            item_title.setText(item.getValue());

            return vi;
        }
    ...
    }
```

As you can see from the above adapter, you have to override two functions of getView() and getDropDownView().

By doing that, you can customize the TextView inside the Spinner as well as the TextView inside the drop down spinner item.

You can use item_title.setTypeface(Null, Typeface.BOLD) and something like that.

I hope this help and look forward to your response.

If you have some questions please inform me.